# Can I inject a dependency into an object which requires data from the object?

Tags: java, spring, ioc-container

I have a User factory which simply gets a User from a UserStore:

```
public class UserFactory
{
    @Autowired
    private UserStore userStore;

    public User getUserFromId(String Id)
    {
        User foundUser = this.userStore.findUser(Id);

        return foundUser;
    }
}
```

Here's my User object:

```
public class User implements Serializable
{
    @Autowired
    private List<Announcer> announcers;  //I want this injected

    private String twitterId;

    private String facebookId;

    public List<Announcer> getAnnouncers()
    {
        //lazy init?
        return this.announcers;
    }

}
```

Each instance in `announcers` is dependent on a corresponding service ID such as `twitterId`, `facebookId`... I could build it lazily in the getter, but I'm curious if there's a way to set of a factory to inject it.  I could also expose a setter, and set it in the UserFactory... but trying to limit exposure.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this link: 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_injecting_collection.htm

See the section named "Injecting Bean References".

I am not aware of a method for doing it without xml config, what I do in these cases is to define the itens to be injected in the list in a xml file and then I inject the beans to the list.

Something like:

```
 <bean id="an1" class="FBAnnouncer"/>
 <bean id="an2" class="TWAnnouncer"/>
 <bean id="user" class="User">
     <property name="announcers">
        <list>
           <ref bean="an1"/>
           <ref bean="an2"/>
        </list>
      </property>
 </bean>
```

Comment: Wouldn't that will give every User the same announcers?  I need to give every User their own announcers based on the services they have registered

Comment: Do you have the list of users to inject? Or are you taking them from a database? If you have the list of users and the list of annoucers for each user, you can use this solution. You could inject the list of users in the user factory the same way the annoucers are injected into the users.